# Azure devops pipeline ssh connection issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was trying to connect to a shared server via ssh but getting connection issue.

From Azure devops pipeline i was running a Bash task and executing ansible playbook to connect to shared server

What i tried so far

1. SSH service connection

azure-pipeline respective task that i had tried is this.
Here i had aleary created a ssh service connection by adding host/user/key details

```
         - task: SSH@0
           displayName: 'Run shell command'
           inputs:
             sshEndpoint: 'ssendpoint'
             runOptions: inline
             inline:
                 ls -lrt
```

Error i got while doing so is this

`2022-11-17T15:18:56.9717340Z ##[error]Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error: All configured authentication methods failed.`

2. Saved ssh private key on secure file under pipeline -> library -> secure files

Respective pipeline code looks like this

```
        - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
          name: sshKey
          displayName: 'Download ssh key'
          inputs:
            secureFile: 'pipeline_key'
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: Install dependencies
          inputs:
             targetType: inline
             script: |
                  python3 -m pip install --user ansible
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName:  Prepare ansible environment
          inputs:
            targetType: inline
            script: |
                 ls -lrt
                 echo [webserver] > ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 echo '$(HOST)' >> ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 echo "" >> ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 echo [webserver:vars] >> ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 echo ansible_ssh_user='$(SSH_USER)' >> ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 echo ansible_ssh_private_key_file=pipeline_key >> ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 echo ansible_ssh_port='$(SSH_PORT)' >> ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 echo ansible_ssh_common_args=\'-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no\' >> ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 ls -lrt ./ci-scripts/
                 cat ./ci-scripts/inventory
                 cd ./ci-scripts
                 cp '$(sshKey.secureFilePath)' pipeline_key
                 chmod 600 pipeline_key
                 ansible -i inventory -m ping webserver
```

inventory is getting created and also the key file looks good when printed from pipeline but then getting folllowing error

```
2022-11-19T07:35:34.5472906Z ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
2022-11-19T07:35:35.9899965Z us.****.us | UNREACHABLE! => {
2022-11-19T07:35:35.9900751Z     "changed": false,
2022-11-19T07:35:35.9905399Z     "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '[us.*****.us]:****' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.\r\nu***-****@us.****.us: Permission denied (publickey).",
2022-11-19T07:35:35.9906494Z     "unreachable": true
2022-11-19T07:35:35.9906996Z }
```

from my laptops terminal i am able to do ssh with same key there without issue, i also have added all azure devops ip's.
If anyone had this issue before or have some suggestion please do share your thought
Thanks!

Comment: Please check the [algorithms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops#supported-algorithms) of your SSH key pair, and also ensure the public key has been copied to the remote machine.
In addition, since the same SSH connection can work well from your laptop, you can try to set up a self-hosted agent on your laptop to run the pipeline job to see whether it can work.

Comment: So i figured this one and it turned out an connectivity issue
I had added all ips listed on these two links but then still it was not able to connect
 [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4) and [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-ip-address-ranges-with-service-tags-for-azure-devops-services/) 
For testing had allowed all traffic from internet and it worked with that, trying to get proper ip list such that i can whitelist them from server end

Answer (score 1):

The [**Azure Service Tags**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-ip-address-ranges-with-service-tags-for-azure-devops-services/) seems is only available to setting NSGs or firewalls for the Azure VNet ([**Azure Virtual Network**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview)), not to your local machines or other VMs which are not hosted on Azure.

To get the possible IP addresses / IP ranges of the MS hosted agents in your [**Azure geography**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies), you can download the [weekly JSON file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) and find all the IP ranges from it. For more details, you can reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking).